# I want convert rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table is

```
  id  name   address
   1  suraj   bhilwara
   2  kapil    jahazpur
   3  nitin   jaipur
```

I want output like this

```
    1               2                   3
suraj            kapil                 nitin
bhilwar           jahzpur             jaipur
```

Please help on this, Thanks in advance

Comment: which rdbms are you using and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` as explained here: [Pivot tables in SQL Server. A simple sample.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)

Comment: my value is not fixed its change frequently

Comment: do you mean it's possible that tomorrow you will have 100 more people in your table? and you want to show 100 more columns?

Comment: this is not something you will be able to do with SQL and anyway it will look really bad. My suggestion is to look for a different tool to visualize your data